# b:dataTable select a single row (and only a single one)

Tags: javascript, datatable, bootsfaces

Good morning. I have a problem with my code in [bootsfaces](http://www.bootsfaces.net/).
I need that my DataTable supports single row selection, but not multiple row selection. However, my table always uses only multiple selection.

This is my code:

```
<b:dataTable id="tableExpedients" fixedHeader="true" style="width:100%;"
            pageLength="6" border="false" responsive="true" lang="es"
            searching="true" var="exp" multiColumnSearch="true" paginated="true"
            select="true" value="#{Expedients.getExpedients()}" custom-options="colReorder: true">
```

I do not get put simple selection, as I have referred these pages:

•http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/DataTable.jsf

•https://datatables.net/reference/option/

Thanks for all.

Comment: Please use good tagging on your questions. And 'datatables' is a completely different component. Why did you add that link? Is bootsfaces datatable based on it?

Comment: yes, bootsfaces DataTable is based on it and if you see my code the property "custom-options" are using a function of datatables.

Thanks for all

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not a bootsfaces nor datatables user. I only follow generic JSF and PrimeFaces. Since this question was wrongly tagged PrimeFaces, I noticed it. Hope someone can help you

Comment: What exactly does not work? In our BootsFaces showcase, the option `select="true"` allows you to select a row. As far as I remember, there's no option yet to tell the server which row you've selected. Is that your problem? Or isn't the row highlighted when you try to select it?

Comment: Or is the problem that it's possible to select multiple rows using the CTRL and/or the SHIFT keys?

Comment: Exactly, our problem is that always allows us to select more than one row. If your pressing CTRL or SHIFT you can select more rows. I just want it to be selectable one.

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Thank for the clarification. I've edited your post in order to make your intent more obvious. If you don't like my edit, don't hesitate to tell me, so we can improve it together. In any case, probably it takes a couple of hours until one of the moderators accepts or rejects my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just implemented the option to limit row selection to individual rows. I'm not entirely sure if that's the bug you report, but now that's your personal feature :).

I didn't want to change the default values of BootsFaces, and I wanted to retain compatibility to PrimeFaces, so I decided to add a new attribute: `selectionMode="single"` switches the dataTable into the single row selection mode, similar to radio buttons. Please note that you still have to set `select="true"`.

The new feature is going to be part of BootsFaces 1.0, which we plan to publish by the end of the month (October 2016). You can test it even earlier by following the instructions at https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/369.

Also see [ticket 531 on our issue tracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/531).

Comment: I'm really grateful for this report. We hope that with this new version we can implement individual selection.

Thank you very much for everything.

Comment: I suggest you test the developer snapshot, so we can fix any error we may have introduced before releasing the final version. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for all , we've tried and it works everything perfectly.